# excel nearest due date

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I have a row with dates and below it I have an empty row where I can type a "C" on any number of cells wanted or needed to get the dates above it, but I only get the first C, so what I am trying to do is actually ignore every "C" that I have wrote that correspond to past dates from today and only give me the closer one or next one from today.

For example: lets say that today is July 1 2018, so I have row 1 with a series of dates like `A1=June 30 2018`, `B1= July 1 2018`, `C1=July 2 2018`, `D1=July 3 2018`, etc and in row2 I have typed C on A2,  C2 and E2 so with `HLOOKUP it returns`June 30 2018`, but I dont want that since that date is now in the past, I want to get the next and more close date after the present day so it should be C2 that is July 2 2018, and so on since the today formula will update as the days pass.

This is to get the next checking date on a project cronogram so all the dates are defined but the result as for each task should be automatically updating to stay relevant for the scehdule, so past dates just dont make any sence to be the results showed on the gantt table diagram, and yes I know it is easy as just to be deleating the "C" that correspond to past dates, but then what is the point of excel then?

[image]

Comment: I don't think formatting is the only issue here. In general, the way you described your problem is very unclear. What you should do isntead is create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflom.com/help/mcve) and edit your qeustion accordingly. As of now it's a pain to even comprehend what you're trying to achieve - and that's after I carefully went through the post and did some formatting and spelling error correction

Comment: Thanks, I apreciate the effort, I know I am not very clear to comunicate, I am working on that personal isuues too, I will remember the advise, and sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

I'll go out on a limb here....  you want to find the first `C` in row 2 after todays date which is in row 1.

- `MATCH` will tell you which column todays date is in:  `MATCH(TODAY(),$1:$1,0)` returns 3 as 2nd July is in C1.
- `INDEX` will return a reference to the cell below todays date when used in conjunction with MATCH:  `INDEX($2:$2,,MATCH(TODAY(),$1:$1,0))`
- `COUNTA` will tell you the last column that's populated with dates in row 1: `COUNTA($1:$1)` returns 9 in my case as I've put dates from `A1:I1`.
- Use `INDEX` again to return a reference to the last cell in row 2.  `INDEX($2:$2,,COUNTA($1:$1))`
- Stick both INDEX's together to get a range reference from todays date to the end of you data:  `INDEX($2:$2,,MATCH(TODAY(),$1:$1,0)):INDEX($2:$2,,COUNTA($1:$1))` - this returns an error as it's returning the reference to multiple cells.
- Now find the first `C` in the referenced range:  `MATCH("C",INDEX($2:$2,,MATCH(TODAY(),$1:$1,0)):INDEX($2:$2,,COUNTA($1:$1)),0)` returns 1 as I've got a C in 2nd July.
- Add the column that todays date is on to the column that was returned (and minus 1 for the hell of it). `SUM(-1,MATCH(TODAY(),$1:$1,0),MATCH("C",INDEX($2:$2,,MATCH(TODAY(),$1:$1,0)):INDEX($2:$2,,COUNTA($1:$1)),0))` returns the column number of the first C on or after todays date.
- Use that number to return a reference to the date in row 1: `=INDEX($1:$1,,SUM(-1,MATCH(TODAY(),$1:$1,0),MATCH("C",INDEX($2:$2,,MATCH(TODAY(),$1:$1,0)):INDEX($2:$2,,COUNTA($1:$1)),0)))`.

**So your final formula is:**

```
=INDEX($1:$1,,SUM(-1,MATCH(TODAY(),$1:$1,0),MATCH("C",INDEX($2:$2,,MATCH(TODAY(),$1:$1,0)):INDEX($2:$2,,COUNTA($1:$1)),0)))
```

Bit long, and I'm sure it can be done in a much shorter formula.
**Edit:**  I also agree with Rawrplus - you could've explained it a bit better.

Comment: Thanks, and yeah you 2 are right, sorry for that, I will try harder to fix my communication "skills".